# How to query vertical and fast read

Tags: mysql

```
code   || Name|| day||ActivityDate||TimeIn    || TimeOut  ||
 001   || Ade || 02 || 2013-08-02 || 10:06:09 || 18:21:03 ||
 001   || Ade || 03 ||2013-08-03  || 11:00:34 || 18:06:56 ||
 001   || Ade || 05 || 2013-08-05 || 09:56:29 || 17:59:56 ||
 002   || Ali || 01 || 2013-08-01 || 09:56:29 || 17:59:56 ||
```

This is my table in phpmyadmin.. 
I want to query, and it will be like the other table..

```
  code|| Name||  1.8TimeIn  ||1.8TimeOut|| 2.8TimeIn|| 2.8TimeOut || And so on>>>
  001 || Ade ||  NULL       || NULL     || 10:06:09 ||  18:21:03  ||  
  002 || Ali ||  09:56:29   || 17:59:56 || NULL     ||  NULL      ||
```

how to use array if i dont want to query, if i use the query, it will take a long long time to read..

my example query :

```
SELECT Name, EmployeeID,
   (SELECT TimeIn  FROM augustatt 
      WHERE EmployeeID=M.EmployeeID AND ActivityDate='2013-08-01') AS '1/8In',
   (SELECT TimeOut  FROM augustatt 
      WHERE EmployeeID=M.EmployeeID AND ActivityDate='2013-08-01') AS '1/8Out' 
FROM augustatt M 
GROUP BY Name,EmployeeID 
ORDER BY Name
```

Comment: Google "mysql pivot table". You could have said "I want rows as columns", and then even if you put that in google - you'd get relevant results. Also, arrays and mysql have nothing to do with each other, so  your questions is slightly ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your base static query should look like this

```
SELECT code, name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ActivityDate = '2013-08-01' THEN timein  END) timein_0108,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ActivityDate = '2013-08-01' THEN timeout END) timeout_0108,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ActivityDate = '2013-08-02' THEN timein  END) timein_0208,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ActivityDate = '2013-08-02' THEN timeout END) timeout_0208,
       ...
 FROM augustatt
 GROUP BY code, name
```

Sample output:

```
+------+------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
| code | name | timein_0108 | timeout_0108 | timein_0208 | timeout_0208 |
+------+------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
|    1 | Ade  | NULL        | NULL         | 10:06:09    | 18:21:03     |
|    2 | Ali  | 09:56:29    | 17:59:56     | NULL        | NULL         |
+------+------+-------------+--------------+-------------+--------------+
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c81f6/4)** demo

---

Now you can do dynamic pivoting this way

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_report()
BEGIN
  SET @sql = NULL;

  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
                      CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN ActivityDate = ''', ActivityDate,
                             ''' THEN timein  END) timein_', 
                             DATE_FORMAT(ActivityDate, '%d%m'), 
                             ',MAX(CASE WHEN ActivityDate = ''', ActivityDate,
                             ''' THEN timeout  END) timeout_', 
                             DATE_FORMAT(ActivityDate, '%d%m')))
    INTO @sql
    FROM augustatt;

  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT code, name,', @sql,
                    '  FROM augustatt
                      GROUP BY code, name');

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And use it

```
CALL sp_report();
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b0f82)** demo

Comment: your query almost like mine.. so in case 2014, i need to recreate dynamic query again.? if run like this, its take so many time, in case i have 100record,

Comment: @user2514863 See updated answer for a dynamic pivot solution.

Comment: your query look fast.. by i need to run in view, which if timein and timeout is datetime datatype, it run so good... but if datatype is time, it just appear all NULL.. and my datatype is time, i can't change because it in view

Comment: if its only 1 to 10 record, its look fine.. but i have around 100 user, it appear NULL, which should contain value